# Visual Studio Cordova exclude files

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Using default settings and the blank Typescript project the build process includes all files in the project directory in the apk/xap \www dir including the d.ts and .ts files. Aside from editing the vs-mda files is there a way to globally (not ant.properties etc.) exclude files from packaging while maintaining intellisense and compiling the .ts files to the correct location?

Another facet of this is that the ionic and angular nuget packages install xxx.js and xxx.min.js into the \scripts dir and both end up in the apk/xap.

I am looking for a method that can be properly employed in project templates to package in .vsix template distributions without requiring the end user to do a bunch of manual edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to accomplish this in VS2013 CTP3.1 is by creating a Cordova hook inside a custom plugin. The hook can be attached to the after_prepare event and you can then write code to remove the files from the correct location  in the generated "platforms" folder under "bld".

See plugin-remove-typescript here: https://github.com/Chuxel/taco-tricks

hook-remove-ts.js:

```
module.exports = function (context) {

    var fs = require("fs");
    var glob = context.requireCordovaModule('glob');    

    context.opts.cordova.platforms.forEach(function(platform) {
        console.log("Processing " + platform);
        // Get all TS files under platforms folder
        glob("platforms/" + platform + "/**/*.ts", function(err, tsFiles) {
            if(err) throw err;
            tsFiles.forEach(function(tsFile) {
                console.log("Deleting " + tsFile);
                fs.unlinkSync(tsFile);
            });
        }); 
    });
}
```

To install it, just grab it from the plugin-remove-typescript folder in the Git repo and drop it in a local folder.  Use the config designer's "custom" tab to select it. You can also modify it to delete other file types by updating the glob syntax in the plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob).

This situation will improve with the upcoming release of VS 2015.

More on Cordova Hooks: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html#Hooks%20Guide

Comment: Thank you. You definitely got me headed in the right direction. I will post what I add to it to clean up an ionic app maximally!

Comment: Although you might want to update this part in the plugin.xml -> <hook type="before_prepare" src="hook-remove-ts.js" />

Answer (score 1):

OK, given the framework Chuck Lantz provided I wrote a plugin that removes the .ts and some clutter files. It also removes unminified js/css when a minified version exists in the same directory(may add a switch to turn that off if needed) and provides a mechanism to globally exclude file patterns and exclude on a per directory basis in release builds without editing the plugin. Excludes directories recursively as of 0.8.6.

It shaved 75% ~5MB -> ~1MB on the app I was working on.

https://github.com/MagicBoxSoftware/vs-cordova-3-1-ignore-files

Answer (score 0):

@Chuck Lantz answer really helped me few years ago.
Since then things cordova evolved.
I tried to use cordova-plugin-exclude-files ([Git](https://github.com/raphinesse/cordova-plugin-exclude-files), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-exclude-files)). It looks OK but:

1. That destroyed my project.
2. It uses after-prepare hook, deleting files after they are already copied.

So i gave up and edited prepare.js (\v2\platforms\android\cordova\lib\prepare.js):

I changed 'updateWwwFrom' function:

```
function updateWwwFrom(cordovaProject, destinations) {
    // use per OS EOL symbol
    var endOfLine = require('os').EOL;
    // build whitelist file path
    var includeFile = path.join(cordovaProject.root, 'build-include.txt');
    // verbosing (will appear in Visual Studio output pane)
    events.emit('verbose', 'Copying files listed in ' + includeFile );
    // read the whitelist file
    var files = require('fs').readFileSync(includeFile, 'utf-8').split(endOfLine);
    // ORIGINAL // clear destination www dir
    shell.rm('-rf', destinations.www);
    // ORIGINAL // create destination www dir
    shell.mkdir('-p', destinations.www);

    // ORIGINAL // Copy source files from project's www directory
    // ORIGINAL shell.cp('-rf', path.join(cordovaProject.locations.www, '*'), destinations.www);

    // copy files from whitelist
    files.forEach( item => copyToWWW( path.join(cordovaProject.locations.www, item) , destinations.www,  path.dirname(item)));

    // ORIGINAL // Override www sources by files in 'platform_www' directory
    shell.cp('-rf', path.join(destinations.platformWww, '*'), destinations.www);

    // ORIGINAL // If project contains 'merges' for our platform, use them as another overrides
    var merges_path = path.join(cordovaProject.root, 'merges', 'android');
    if (fs.existsSync(merges_path)) {
        events.emit('verbose', 'Found "merges" for android platform. Copying over existing "www" files.');
        var overrides = path.join(merges_path, '*');
        shell.cp('-rf', overrides, destinations.www);
    }
}
```

Added helper function:

```
// copy files from whitelist
function copyToWWW(source, dest, dirname)
{
    var destWithDirName = path.join(dest, dirname);
    shell.mkdir('-p', destWithDirName);
    shell.cp('-rf', source, destWithDirName );
}
```

And created build-include.txt file in my projects root. Sample content:

```
subdir/*
subdir2/file.png
```